# GitHub does not download entire source in ZIP

Tags: git, github, download

I'm trying to download [this](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/tree/master/bigbluebutton-client) from GitHub, but clicking the "Download ZIP" link fetches me a 113 MB ZIP File with only 4 of the 10 source folders:

- bbb-api-demo
- bbb-common-message
- bbb-video
- bbb-voice-conference

Am I doing something wrong? Why can't I download the other folders? The download doesn't seem to be interrupting so why is the trunk/source incomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got all the folders when I used the standard link:

https://nodeload.github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/zipball/master

You can get similar for tags too.

PS: The link that you have mentioned just points to a tree which is for a subfolder in your project. I don't suppose you wanted to point to the subfolder, but the entire project.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are at the root of the project at: https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton

Here is a direct link if you need it: https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/zipball/master

Also know that you can use the terminal command

```
git clone https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton.git
```

Windows can also use git but you need to install it
These directions may help if you want it: http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/

Answer (score 0):

git clone the project and checkout the tag that corresponds with the zip file you tried to download.

If that tag looks ok, then maybe contact some github support since it could be a issue with their service?